# How to check for not null value in relationship table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these three tables in a PostgreSQL db and as you can see books has an author field (referencing users) and users has a company_id field referencing companies.

```sql
create table companies (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar not null
);


create table users (
    id serial primary key,
    email varchar not null,
    company_id int,
    constraint fk_company
        foreign key(company_id)
            references companies(id)
);


create table books (
    id serial primary key,
    title varchar not null,
    author_id integer not null,
    constraint fk_author
        foreign key(author_id)
            references users(id)
);
```

A user may or may not belong to a company, but to create a book the user must have a company reference.

I am wondering if there is a way to implement a `CHECK` constraint on the `author_id` column which would ensure that the author has a company reference.

Maybe something like: `author_id integer not null CHECK(users.company_id is not null)`, but of course this doesn't work.

Is there some sort of constraint I can use to check columns in relations?

Also am I even approaching this problem in the right way?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Create an entry in `companies` for `Freelancer` & use that for independent Authors.

Comment: This could work, but it'll be a workaround. Ideally I don't want to create a books record unless the user belongs to a company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at constraints:

A `Publisher` can have zero or more publications.

An `Author/User` can have zero or more books Authored.

A `Book` will have one `Publisher` & `one or more Authors`.

Move the `company_id` constraint to `books` table. If & when an User/Author[s] publishes a book; They become a new `Publishing Company` and an entry to `Publishing Company`.